# How do you enable titlebar icons in 22.04

Tags: themes, settings, titlebar

How do you enable icons in window titlebars, it appears in ubuntu 22.04 they have been hidden for all applications?

The examples below are from the same java program running on ubuntu and windows.
The java code that sets the icon is

```
pstage.getIcons().add(new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("i100.png"))));
```

[ubuntu titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmL2R.png)

I would like the icon to appear (anywhere will do) in the titlebar as it does in windows.

[windows titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOGrK.png)

I would like to find the ubuntu gnome setting/tweak which allows icons to be displayed please.

This is the result of Linux Genie's suggestion below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to enable app icon in titlebar:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout menu:appmenu,minimize,maximize,close
```

Comment: I don't think that this will display the application icon on the titlebar. I don't think that GNOME even supports displaying application icon on the titlebar.

Comment: It does. . https://imgsh.net/a/dqHgDEo.jpg

Comment: ok, so that works for some applications, e.g. console now shows an icon. but not for others including the java apps, it just adds a 3 dash menu to the top left.

Comment: btw the command to undo the suggested by FedKad is
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'

Comment: Gnome setting/Tweak works only with Gnome applications.